# Using "new" in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm following an example on how to use *require.js* and *backbone.js*. In the example, the model does not use `new` when it returns. In my code I have to use `new` otherwise I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'toJSON'
```

Doesn't work:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var personModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
            conversations: 'No Conversations'
    },
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });
  return personModel;
});
```

Works:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var personModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
            conversations: 'No Conversations'
    },
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });
  return new personModel;
});
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: I initially thought it was a problem with the scope of personModel, but i misread the code. Therefore, I think i'm going to go with @rjz on this one. +1 to both of you for good question and response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Backbone.Model.extend` returns a constructor function--not an actual object. The constructor isn't an object (and consequently won't have any properties) until it's been instantiated using `new` (as in your second example). That means that `toJSON` isn't available, either, and you end up with the error you're seeing.

When you're ready to actually create a new `personModel`, you might do it something like this (I'll assume that the module you described above has been defined as "Person"):

```
define("main", ["Person"], function (Person) {
  var me = new Person({ conversations: ['Hello, world']});
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of your application looks like, but there probably isn't any reason to instantiate it inside the module you've outlined. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: +1 I needed to "new" the Model when I was initializing my ItemView.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a more detailed explanation, whenever you do a new in JS, the object gets the __proto reference and hence access to the prototype variables and methods - this is good practice whenever inheritance is desired.

To illustrate:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype = {
  canWalk: true,
  sit: function() {
    this.canWalk = false
    }
}

var incompleteAnimal = Animal('cat');
alert (incompleteAnimal.canWalk) //error undefined variable

var completeAnimal = new Animal('cat') 
alert (completeAnimal.canWalk); //true
```

Only when you do a new will you get access to the canWalk variable and sit function

Comment: In my example, where is the "best" place to call new? In the model definition? Will this pollute the DOM with more variables?